# Are there fonts that include musical note characters?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, font

On my Mac, there is a font that contains the *BEAMED EIGHT NOTES* Unicode character, but there are no fonts that contains the *MUSICAL SYMBOL PLUS NOTEHEAD* or the *MUSICAL SYMBOL QUARTER NOTE* Unicode character.

Are there fonts that contain such characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(The links to the Musica typeface don't seem to lead anywhere useful.)*

Uptake of the Musical Symbols in Unicode has been very limited: there were already fonts that allowed music symbols to be incorporated into text blocks, such as the *Bach Musicological Font* (which is now hard to find); and notation applications use their own fonts, whose symbols tend to use the 'ASCII' glyph range.

However, over the last few years, a standard for music notation symbols in Unicode has been formulated, called [SMuFL](https://github.com/w3c/smufl). SMUFL-compliant fonts will also include glyphs in the Unicode reserved locations that you are after.

The SMuFL reference font, Bravura, comes in two versions, one for notation software, and the other, Bravura Text, for use in text. Either of these will include the characters you want. You can download the fonts [here](https://github.com/w3c/smufl/releases).

Answer (score 3):

The Musica typeface (available on [Unicode Fonts for Ancient Scripts](https://dn-works.com/ufas/)) has both of the Unicode characters you mention; I tested it with the Character Viewer on Mac OS 10.6.6 and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I can't see the Musica typeface on that link.

Comment: @benwiggy  Probably it's the Symbola font instead.  Musica is a font available on various other sites, no idea if it is useful.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing the [Musica font](http://users.teilar.gr/%7Eg1951d/Musica306.zip) from [page](http://users.teilar.gr/%7Eg1951d/). This will install the musical notes you need (free). You can then test it out on this [page](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/musical_symbols.html).

Hope this helps.